# Potential problem found: The configured data type factory might cause problems...

Tags: h2, spring, hibernate, java

Всем Добрый День! Пишу тесы на класс из слоя DAO:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:data.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
public class HibernateUserDaoTest {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Test
    @DatabaseSetup(value = { "classpath:my_user_tb.xml" })
    @ExpectedDatabase(value = "classpath:create_my_user_tb.xml", assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT)
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("1");
        User user = null;
        Role role1 = new Role();
        role1.setId(1);
        role1.setName("USER");
        user = new User(2, "Newman", "", "new@mail.ru", "Numan", "Lastman",
                Date.valueOf("1914-07-28"), role1);
        userDao.create(user);
    }
    ......
    }
```

Всё нормально проходит но, в консоль вылазит на каждом тесте варнинг:

> WARN :
> org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData
> - Potential problem found: The configured data type factory 'class
> org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DefaultDataTypeFactory'
> might cause problems with the current
> database 'H2' (e.g. some datatypes may
> not be supported properly). In rare
> cases you might see this message
> because the list of supported database
> products is incomplete (list=[derby]).
> If so please request a java-class
> update via the forums.If you are using
> your own IDataTypeFactory extending
> DefaultDataTypeFactory, ensure that
> you override getValidDbProducts() to
> specify the supported database
> products.

data.xml:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

        <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
            p:location="jdbc.properties" />

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
            p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

        <bean name="userService"
            class="com.service.UserServiceImpl" />
        <bean name="roleService"
            class="com.service.RoleServiceImpl" />

        <bean name="userDao" class="com.dao.HibernateUserDao" />
        <bean name="roleDao" class="com.dao.HibernateRoleDao" />
```

Много копал в google но толкового решения не нашёл, как это вылечить.
Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже погуглил:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942965/dbunit-warning-abstracttablemetadata
- http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#typefactory
- http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/dbunit/ext/h2/H2DataTypeFactory.html

Короче, нужно зарегистрировать фабрику специфичную для используемой вами БД.

---

Насколько понимаю, вы также пользуетесь проектом http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/ ? Там на странице есть раздел "Custom IDatabaseConnections" в котором описывается как сконфигурировать всё это дело.

В вашем случае, кажется, должно быть так:

```
<bean id="dataTypeFactory" class="org.dbunit.ext.h2.H2DataTypeFactory" />

<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
    <property name="datatypeFactory" ref="dataTypeFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConnection" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="databaseConfig" ref="dbUnitDatabaseConfig"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

В данном случае мы создали бин `dbUnitDatabaseConnection` который `DbUnitTestExecutionListener` будет искать в контексте:

> A bean named "dbUnitDatabaseConnection" or "dataSource" is expected in the
>   ApplicationContext associated with the test.

[Цитата из из JavaDoc-а](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/apidocs/com/github/springtestdbunit/DbUnitTestExecutionListener.html).

Comment: Вы как-нибудь настраиваете DbUnit? Если да, то покажите соответствующий код/конфиги.

Answer (score 1):

Со **Spring-Boot** можно использовать такой конфиг для лечения этого

```
@Configuration
public class DbUnitConfiguration {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean dbUnitDatabaseConnection() {
    DatabaseConfigBean bean = new DatabaseConfigBean();
    bean.setDatatypeFactory(new H2DataTypeFactory());

    DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean dbConnectionFactory = new DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean(dataSource);
    dbConnectionFactory.setDatabaseConfig(bean);
    return dbConnectionFactory;
    }
}
```